# reuse color keys across heatmaps

Tags: r, heatmap

I am using heatmap 2 to generate heatmaps and I'd like to reuse the same color ranges/keys across different data sets.

for instance, I am repeating the same experiment, but on one run, I have the data points in the range `[0, 10]`, while on the other, the data points are in the range `[0, 20]`. currently, the heatmap would map `red->white` to `[0, 10]` and `[0, 20]`, depending on the dataset.

Is there any way I can use an "absolute" color range across all my heatmaps, so thatthe same color would represent the same value for all my heatmaps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reuse colour ranges across different heatmaps, you should explicitly specify the breaks in the colour range. You've not provided a reproducible example, so this is a general example:

```
library("gplots")
breaks = c(seq(-5, 0, length.out=128), 
           seq(0, 3, length.out=128))
heatmap.2(hm_data, dendrogram='row', Colv=FALSE,
              col=bluered(255), key=TRUE, labRow=row_names,
              breaks=breaks, symkey=FALSE, density.info="none", 
              trace="none", cexRow=0.5, cexCol=0.75)
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks. I was given "breaks" an integer instead of a vector and that obviously made it use min:max range, duh, :P.